# Converting CSV information from str > float > int then assigning it to a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

Current code...

```
import csv
import itertools

students = {}
def studentGradeCSV():
    with open('/Users/home/Downloads/gradebook-export.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        global students
        students = {}
        for row in reader:
            name = row['Last Name'] + ', ' + row['First Name']
            grade = row['Overall']
            new_grade = []
            for g in grade:
                try:
                    v = int(float(g))
                    new_grade.append(v)
                except ValueError:
                    new_grade.append(g)
            for n, gr in itertools.product(name, new_grade):
                students[n] = gr
```

Example of 'grade' indexes - 'N/A', '92.13', '100', '87.2', '91', '0'

The 'grade' variable are strings. I'm tying to convert them to integers before assigning them as key values to values in the 'name' variable. I've previously been able to convert the 'grade' int keys to name value but they were assigned incorrectly because dictionary doesn't grab them in the correct order.

Unsure where to go from here??

Comment: What does your data look like? What output are you getting - 'incorrectly' is not very descriptive. Why `for g in grade:`, grade is just a single value from `row['Overall']` so this will iterate character by character. Also the `itertools.product()` seems overkill for a single name, if `new_grade` has multiple values (which it doesn't look like) they would over-write the `key`.

Comment: @AChampion sorry. With this current code it just print a letter. I have had it look like this `('Surname, FirstName', ['N', '/', 'A']),` on previous attempts but it currently looks like this `('a', 'A')`. Needing the full value from grade variable. Hope this helps.

Comment: This was the initial code `def studentGradeCSV(f):
    with open(f) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        global students
        students = {}
        for row in reader:
            name = row['Last Name'] + ', ' + row['First Name']
            grade = row['Overall'] 
            students[name] = grade` but trying to get any str/float values to change to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using `for` loops for single values:

```
    name = row['Last Name'] + ', ' + row['First Name']
    grade = row['Overall']
    try:
        grade = int(float(grade))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    students[name] = grade
```

Your `for` loops and `itertools.product` treat strings as a sequence of characters, e.g.

```
for g in 'N/A':
```

Will produce `new_grade = ['N', '/', 'A']`.
Then:

```
itertools.product("Name", ['N', '/', 'A']
```

Produces the sequence `('N', 'N'), ('N', '/'), ('N', 'A'), ('a', 'N'), ...` which isn't what you are looking.